# Comparison between the same values is always false

Tags: python, python-3.x

import random

```
def g1to9():
    a = random.randint(1,9)
    wt = 0 
    b = input("Guess a number from 1 to 9:")
    if a == b:
        print("You guessed it correctly, it took you {} tries".format(wt))
    while True:
        if a != b:
            print("You are wrong!")
            b = input("Guess a number from 1 to 9:")
            wt += 1
```

I am trying to create a game "Guess a number from 1 to 9". But when I run it I check all the numbers but a is never equal to b. I tried to make a a global variable,but it didn't work. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Convert input taken to an int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

b would of type `str` as it is an input. You need to cast it to an int first. You can do that by:

```
b = int(input("Guess a number from 1 to 9:"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But when I guess it correctly, the program just stops

Comment: No problem! If that solved your problem, make sure to accept this answer by clicking the tick mark :)

Comment: That is because you don't have anything in your while loop for that case. Consider moving your first if conditional inside the loop

Comment: Glad I could help :)